Stop drastic deforming in rig; Bone that rotates towards camera
I am trying to twist a mesh in order for the top part to follow the camera. At the moment I am using an armature modifier with weight paint in a gradient-like shape, and the bone has a damped track constraint towards the camera.
Here's the weight paint:

This is how it is supposed to work, the camera is in the front of the object currently.

In here the armature is rotating towards the camera, but the object is twisting really weirdly/drastically.

And in here the damping gets kinda weirder, and the object rotates downwards even though the camera is not down.

Before this I've tried multiple things, like having the parts separated and merged by geometry nodes in the external vertexes, or having a "mesh deform" modifier connected to hooks that rotate towards the camera. All of these have failed with varying effects :p
Is there a way I can fix this armature in order to try and do what I want? Or is there an alternative method that could work too?
